# TSQL: Select with dynamic WHERE come from another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, where-clause

I am developing a solution for statistic data for a customer and now i need to select some rows `from a table` (**sell data**) by using dynamic condition that come from **another table** (filled by the customer and it can change daily).

Also i need to use a cursor to perform more calculation and other stuff so this is the scenario:

```
DECLARE cRiga CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    -- here i will put the SELECT ...
OPEN cRiga
    FETCH NEXT FROM cRiga INTO @field1, @field2, @field3, ...
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- do some stuff here ...
        FETCH NEXT FROM cRiga INTO @field1, @field2, @field3, ...
    END
CLOSE cRiga
DEALLOCATE cRiga
```

this is the **Condition Table** where i can find the dynamic condition (see the colum Completa = 0)

```
IDIncentive CdMarca CdSettore CdGruppo Completa
----------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
1           COES    NULL      NULL     1
1           DELONG  10        0024     0  <
1           RHOSS   NULL      NULL     1
1           SILE    10        0012     0  <
1           SILE    11        0025     0  <
1           THERMI  NULL      NULL     1
....... more rows ...
```

To be more clear i try to explode the SQL required in many queries as:

```
Select Field1, ... from SELLDATA 
where IDIncentive=1 and CdMarca='DELONG' and CdSettore=10 and CdGruppo='0024'
UNION ALL
Select Field1, ... from SELLDATA 
where IDIncentive=1 and CdMarca='SILE' and CdSettore=10 and CdGruppo='0012'
UNION ALL
Select Field1, ... from SELLDATA 
where IDIncentive=1 and CdMarca='SILE' and CdSettore=11 and CdGruppo='0025'
```

As u can imagine i cant do that because the conditions change daily by the customer so my question is:

**How i can create a select that have all the conditions (as my example above) to use in the cursor ? There are a way ?**

Thanks for who can help me and please advise if need more information to make more clear this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your already existing ConditionTable table to filter SELLDATA by means of join: no cursor, no union all.

```
Select Field1, ... 
  from SELLDATA 
 inner join ConditionTable
    ON SELLDATA.IDIncentive=ConditionTable.IDIncentive 
   and SELLDATA.CdMarca=ConditionTable.CdMarca
   and SELLDATA.CdSettore=ConditionTable.CdSettore
   and SELLDATA.CdGruppo=ConditionTable.CdGruppo
 where ConditionTable.Completa = 0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and i need the cursor due i need to do more analisys for each record. Your answer isnt the solution that i was looking for but it give me the right way and the ispiration so i accept it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually need a cursor (and 9 times out of 10 you don't), you can use dynamic SQL and sp_executesql to create arbitrary cursors at run time:

```
declare @cursor cursor
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @dynamic_part nvarchar(max)
declare @name sysname

set @dynamic_part = 'tables'
set @sql = '
  set @cursor = cursor static for select top (100) name from sys.'+@dynamic_part+'
  open @cursor'

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@cursor cursor output', @cursor output 
while 1=1 begin
  fetch next from @cursor into @name
  if @@fetch_status <> 0 break
  print @name
end
close @cursor deallocate @cursor
```

Alternately, you can create temp table, populate the temp table via dynamic SQL, and then define the cursor against the temp table:

```
declare @cursor cursor
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @dynamic_part nvarchar(max)
declare @name sysname

if object_id('tempdb..#these_things') is not null drop table #these_things
create table #these_things (name sysname)

set @dynamic_part = 'tables'
set @sql = 'insert #these_things (name) select top (100) name from sys.'+@dynamic_part
exec (@sql)

set @cursor = cursor fast_forward for select name from #these_things
open @cursor
while 1=1 begin
  fetch next from @cursor into @name
  if @@fetch_status <> 0 break
  print @name
end
close @cursor deallocate @cursor
```

This is probably a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Peter really thanks for your answer and code. I appreciate your big effort and time spent. And all this let me improve more :) And i know about the cursor but this time i need it because i need to do more calculation, data analisys and more stuff for each record. +1

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, so glad you noticed that. Spread the love! Also of note: a) cursor variables, that automatically go out of scope and clean themselves up at the end of a batch or procedure, b) static cursors to snapshot a recordset defined against system tables and thereby minimize contention, and c) fast forward cursors to iterate over rows that have already been copied to local temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I think subqueries should help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html